# What is this <Module> Type in an assembly

Tags: .net, reflection

Each time I open an assembly in reflector, I see this special `<Module>` type that shows up.   Recently, I came across an assembly that has a static method defined in this type and I want to invoke it through reflection. Is this possible?

Btw, this method has `privatescope` `hidebysig` method attributes

**EDIT:**

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
Type moduleType = assembly.GetType("<Module>");
```

The above piece of code returns a null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have time to experiment to find the right form of name to use, but if you use `Assembly.GetTypes()` to get *all* of the types in the assembly, you may be able to find it that way. Bear in mind that an assembly can have many modules. Use `Assembly.GetModules()` to find all of them.

Comment: That was the inspiration I needed. Thank you!   
The method I was looking for was a global method (about which I have never heard before) and was not part of any type. But for some reason, reflector decided to show it under the type '<module>'. 
 

I was able to fetch the method using assembly.GetModules()[0].GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Static)

Btw, the <Module> type doesn't show up when I use Assembly.GetTypes() or when I use ILDasm.